# Move file from the stage to archive (Issue :- Atleast one file doesnt move)

Tags: c#, .net

I have a file watcher, once the file is created in the stage directory, I want to move it to archive. When i manually copy file from a folder to stage, atleast one of those files doesnt move

Here is my code

```
 class Program
    {
        public static String stagepath = @"C:\Users\a\Desktop\\stage\";
        public static String archivePath = @"C:\Users\a\Desktop\archive\";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MonitorDirectory(stagepath);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = path;
            watcher.Created += FileCreated;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


        }

        private static void FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!FileIsReady(stagepath+e.Name)) return;

            System.IO.File.Move(stagepath + e.Name, archivePath + e.Name);

            //Console.WriteLine("File is available");

        }

        private static  bool FileIsReady(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand there are similar questions asked, but none of them is resolving my issue, so posted again.

Comment: That worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to subscribe to `FileSystemWatcher.Changed` event. In your case you can just change the event name and the code should work.

But of course, there's no universal way of detecting that the writer had finished his work. You must invent one which will suit your needs. For example:

- Assume the writer will always lock the file only once. This means
  that the watcher can start his work right after the file becomes
  unlocked (that's what you get if you follow my advice)
- Use a checksum or any other method of validating file consistency. If
  you can accomplish that, you should be able to avoid unnecessary
  locks and exceptions. Just don't move the file until it is valid.
- Think about why you're moving a file right after it was created
  somewhere else. Most of the time you should avoid that kind of
  operations, because the writer starts doing somewhat a strange job.